# Lighting inside of a MESH

Tags: mesh, lighting

I added a torus mesh to my workspace and placed a light on the inside of it and the camera. When I go into camera view in Material mode, I can see the interior surface.. However, when I go into the Render view, it's black using the camera view.

However, from the ouside view, it looks like the surface of the taurus is lit up from the light source on the inside...

What needs to be done for the inside of the taurus to be illuminated by the light on the inside?
Thanks
Harry

Comment: I think you need to flip the normals so that they point inwards

Comment: Still doesn't work with a sun lamp, but the interior gets illuminated with a Point light and Spot light.